# How do I pass a existing variable into a pyqt5 ui file that is called?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm using PyQt5 for my interface. I want to import the link variable from my **main program** into the **GUI program** so that it can display the **link fetched from my main program**.

This is how I want it to work:

**Link is fetched --> Link is put into a variable --> Link is passed into the GUI file --> GUI displays the image link in the GUI.**

Watered down version of my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.close()

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\amete\Documents\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://myanimelist.net/search/all?q=one%20piece&cat=all")

search = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name="q"]')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[@name="q"]')))
#  Clears the field
search.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'a')
search.send_keys(Keys.DELETE)

#  The field is now cleared and the program can type whatever it wants
search.send_keys(Anime)
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

#  Accept the cookies
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="qc-cmp2-ui"]/div[2]/div/button[3]'))).click()

#  Added this wait
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//h2[@id="anime"]//ancestor::div[@class="content-left"]//article[1]/div[contains(@class, "list")][1]/div[contains(@class, "information")]/a[1]')))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/article[1]/div[1]/div[2]/a[1]'))).click()


#Grabs the link of the picture
piclink = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/div[1]/a/img').get_attribute('src')
print (piclink)
```

.UI code

```
import sys
import requests
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap


    class Ui_MainWindow(object):
        def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
            MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
            MainWindow.resize(537, 402)
            self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
            self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
            self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
            self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 221, 291))
            Image = QImage()
            Image.loadFromData(requests.get(piclink).content)
            self.label.setText("")
            self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(Image))
            self.label.setObjectName("label")
            self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
            self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 190, 131, 41))
            self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
            self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
            self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 190, 131, 41))
            self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
            self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
            self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 10, 281, 61))
            font = QtGui.QFont()
            font.setPointSize(20)
            self.label_2.setFont(font)
            self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
            self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
            self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 90, 161, 41))
            font = QtGui.QFont()
            font.setPointSize(22)
            self.label_3.setFont(font)
            self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
            MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
            self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
            self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 537, 21))
            self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
            MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
            self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
            self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
            MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
    
            self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
            QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    
        def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
            _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
            MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
            self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Yes"))
            self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "No"))
            self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Is this the right anime?"))
            self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow",str(Titles)))
    
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        import sys
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I need to pass "URlink" variable into the user interface file

Comment: your question is unclear, please provide a [mre]

Comment: Ok but I didn't think it was needed

Comment: Chunks of code are not an MRE. Also read [ask] and review the [tour]

Comment: 1. Avoid unnecessary adjectives so I recommend you read the site's code of conduct. 2. The DV (or UV) do not have to be explained so I will ignore those comments. If I consider that a post is bad for not providing an MRE or being unclear then I will give it my DV.

Comment: Why not pass by the thread?
It doesn't benefit either of us
Thanks anyway

Comment: You say *pass*, from where to where? You don't provide adequate context. You are focused on the trivial: "minimal", instead of the relevant: "reproducible", with that code I can not reproduce the context so do not remove code but add the necessary code to understand the problem.

Comment: I literally said, passing a urlink variable from my main program into the UI file?
How else am I supposed to explain it?
I did add the code with an edit,but you ignored it when you said "Chucks of code are not an MRE"
Then I posted a "watered down version" would still allow you to solve my problem in my eyes but you continue to bash me for no reason.
I'll edit it again with my full UI code but the majority of my main program code isn't necessary.

Comment: Then show yout main file and ui file(complete code + imports)

Comment: Added the code with imports

Comment: In your main file where do you use the GUI?

Comment: Basically, since I didn't know how to do import a variable from my main program into the GUI program, I instead pasted the code into my main program. It didn't look nice and was an eyesore. That's why I don't have any code calling the GUI. 
That's why I asked the question and because of that GUI wouldn't have worked since it needs a link from the internet. So that's the reason there isn't any code calling the GUI.

Comment: You realize that if you do not provide the information that resulted from providing an MRE it was impossible for the community to understand the problem.

Comment: @ametefe Please don't post the same question in a new thread. Doing that could contributre to a question ban by the system. Edit this question to provide more background to help the community solve it instead. If you want the comments deleted, flag one with a custom flag and ask a moderator to do so, or ask the other user to delete their comments and delete your comments by yourself.

Comment: @ametefe 1. Please mind your language; 2. Maybe yours is just lack of experience or knowledge of the correct terminology, but the phrase "How do I import a variable from one program into a UI program with pyqt5" doesn't make sense; also, which of them is the main program? 3. If you don't know how to properly use an UI created in Designer, you should have said that from the beginning, since we cannot assume what you do know and what you don't; read how to properly use those files in the guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Comment: It's just frustrating but ok 
I'm just explaining it how I explain all my other question but I just feel his comment came across as rude and not trying to understand my problem with questions of his own like other people n this community.

I'll try to explain my program again
How do I send a variable from my main program into the UI. I need the "Image" to equal the "URL" variable from my main program. The link is fetched from the main program, and then I want it to be passed into the GUI.

Comment: @ametefe Question *How send* is very generic and the answer depends on the real context that is why I have insisted on the MRE, I need to know to what extent you have advanced, what you intend to achieve and what problems you have. It is like saying to a mountaineer: how do you climb the Andes or the Himalayas? Well I will tell you: give me more information than you know since the general question is irresponsible.

Comment: @eyllanesc The thing is, my question is generic in nature. It's nothing complex. I feel like I have done this solution before but I have just forgotten how to do it. I'm trying to add as much context as I can but it still makes my question sound generic.
It seems like you understand the problem now. I'll check out the solution

Comment: @ametefe generic is not the opposite of complex. Your "generic", though, is *vague*, as there are lots of different ways for which your "generic" could be answered, and if we don't have enough information about your knowledge and situation, we really cannot answers: you can't expect we would provide any possible answer to a generic question that, as already said, is also badly asked, since your usage of "import", "send", "variable" and "program" is just confusing. That said, even if you think a comment is rude, how would answering "you are just shi***ng on me" improve *any* attitude?

Comment: @ametefe An example of generic is: what is living? What is a planet? They are simple concepts (many times intuitive) but they do not have a concrete answer until the community takes the time to define them clearly, but in general they are blurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are not modularized your project, the logic is to create functions or classes that implement the necessary logic and that are independent, after that join them so that the functions and objects interact. On the other hand, do not modify the code generated by pyuic but create another class that inherits from a suitable QWidget and fill them.

In this case, you must execute the scraping and download tasks in another thread since they consume a lot of time, and send the information to the main thread.

Considering the above, the solution is:

```py
import threading

from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

import requests

from gui import Ui_MainWindow


def find_link(anime):
    # ...
    piclink = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/div[1]/a/img').get_attribute('src')
    return piclink


def download_image(link):
    image = QImage()
    image.loadFromData(requests.get(link).content)
    return image


class AnimeManager(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal(QImage)

    def start(self, anime):
        threading.Thread(target=self._do_work, args=(anime,), daemon=True).start()

    def _do_work(self, anime):
        link = find_link(anime)
        image = download_image(link)
        self.finished.emit(image)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.anime_manager = AnimeManager()
        self.anime_manager.finished.connect(self.handle_finished)
        self.anime_manager.start("Pokemon")

    def handle_finished(self, image):
        pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(image)
        self.ui.label.setPixmap(pixmap)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Note: restore Ui_MainWindow class.

Comment: Why shouldn't I edit the code from Qt Designer? Does it lead to problems? Since I'm new to it, only made sense to edit it. As for the rest, I think I can understand what you are doing but it seems a bit confusing compared to my original code.

Comment: @ametefe 1. Yes, at least a week there are about 5 questions caused by following that bad practice, 2. I have only modularized it, your code is there.

Comment: @ametefe there are *lots* of good and important reasons for which it shouldn't be edited. The most important is also the most simple: suppose you want to change the UI because you need another button or change the order of the widgets. The result is that any change done to the python file would be lost, and even if keep a copy, merging them can be painful and almost always leads to errors due to mistyping or wrong copy/paste. In the last versions of PyQt they also added a clear warning: *Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing*. So, no, it doesn't make sense to edit it.

Comment: Note that "know what you are doing" here means knowing what those `UI_MainWindow` classes are, how they're used and behave: for instance, a common error is directly subclassing those classes (which is completely pointless) and/or override Qt methods, but that won't work since they are basic python objects and there's nothing to override. Modularity is a base concept of OOP, pyuic respects it by creating a standalone *convenience* object that's not intended to be modified. If you want to change the *base* UI, use Designer; if you want to add functionality, use code logic to work *with* that UI.

Comment: As already suggested, study the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) (specifically the single and multiple inheritance approaches). You'll see that there's no mention there about editing those files, which are **always** imported and used as they are. Be aware that there are "tutorials" around the web that *do* suggest editing: if you find any of them, just close and forget them, as they are **totally** wrong and it's clear that they do *not* know what they're doing (and what's worst is that they are also "teaching" it).

Comment: @eyllanesc I tried to limit length to avoid another comment (thus not leaving space for the @), wasn't it enough for the first one?

Comment: @musicamante No, each comment is independent. So if you don't use @ then the notification will reach the owner of the post, that is, me.

Comment: @eyllanesc Right, I forgot about that, and I always thought that the owner always gets notifications even if addressed to others. Will keep it in mind.